# New home with out buildings

Tags: electrical

I installed a 400 amp meter pedestal with 2 200 amp breakers. 1 breaker is 200 amp to the house. Can I install the new panel more than 10 feet into the home?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can.**

The rule about putting the main panel in a house either on the same wall, either outside next to the meter or inside immediately opposite the meter, is because historically there was no overcurrent protection at the meter. So in order to minimize the problems between meter and main breaker (or Rule of 6 set of breakers or fuses), the distance between meter and main panel was kept as short as possible. This is still the case in areas that don't require an outside disconnect.

However, in any of the following situations:

- "Meter main" that combines the meter with a main panel
- Meter with a main panel next to it

your inside panel is *not* your main panel, so there is no concern about the distance.

It is not clear what you have, but it is either a meter main with 2 x 200A breakers or it is a meter right next to a main lug panel containing 2 x 200A breakers. You won't (in a normal residential setup) find actual 400A breakers, so in this setup it is critical to have the meter and the main panel close together. And you have that.

In fact, while your pedestal may be right next to your home, and a 200A subpanel in your home (which can be a "main panel" style, as long as ground and neutral are kept separate) may end up within 10 feet of your pedestal, it is quite common to have the second 200A breaker feed an outbuilding such as a detached garage or workshop, that is a long distance away.

Comment: 400 meter main with 2 200 amp breakers Siemens 1 to feed the house other with 16 spots for beakers and feed through to feed a shop.  I want to put the panel in the center part of the house with no 200 amp main. This is In Idaho they use 2017 code

Comment: That adds one possible twist. Is the 400A meter main *at the house* or is it some distance away from the house?

Comment: Though just so you know, any decent size 200A panel **will** either come with a main breaker (whether you need it or not) or have a space for one. You're not sticking some wimpy 12 space panel in the middle of your house, even if it has a 200A bus. So the actual *cost* of having that 200A "main breaker" in the panel in the middle of your house is essentially $ 0.00. Actually *less* because it is *cheaper* to buy a "main panel bundle" that includes a 200A 30 space (or larger) panel with a 200A main breaker and "bonus breakers" for several circuits than it is to buy a smaller subpanel + breakers

Comment: But as long as there is a "disconnect" for the building, which is satisfied by the 200A breaker in the meter main if the meter main is right next to your house, then no you don't need a "main breaker" in the panel inside your house. And in either case, that panel can be anywhere in your house.

Comment: I want to have the panel in the house not in the garage as it is 37’ wide and didn’t want to run so much wire over the garage. Can I run it under ground to inside wall? What code can I find this under?

Comment: I started my answer off with "yes, you can". The question of "can you put the panel in the middle of the house" is 100% resolved - **YES**. What I am saying is "there is no reason not to use a panel that includes a 200A main breaker" - it will likely save money (really!) or at least not cost extra, and gives you the advantage that if you want to turn off the panel to work inside it safely you can do so without having to go outside to the meter main. As far as **how** to run the 200A feed from the meter main to the inside panel, that is an entirely different question.

Comment: @Bob, if you have specific new questions that this hasn't answered, please ask a whole new question. Feel free to include a link (use the `Share` text under your question to get a link) to this question, but asking more questions in the comments isn't the way this site works.